# Couldn't Click Bottom using xPath Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I think I pretty much tried every xPath within the Bottom element to download an Excel file by using xPath methods but don't know why they are incorrect. Besides, I also tried `Click()` and `Keys.ENTER`. Any helps would be very appreciated! Please let me know if you need more details.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\My\Path\chromedriver")
driver.get('https://reo-central.com/Default.aspx')

elem = driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$LoginControl$LoginControl$UserName')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('MyAccount')

password = driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$LoginControl$LoginControl$Password')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('MyPassword')
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlResponsibleParty'))
select.select_by_value('344860')

Upcoming_Tasks = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'WebPagexPath'))
)

print(Upcoming_Tasks.text)

Upcoming_Tasks.click()
Upcoming_Tasks.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

[image]

```
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn">
```

xPath:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_OverdueItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_GridToolbar"]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]
```

> **Keys.Enter:**   WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
>
> **Click():**  WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point
>   (244, 149). Other element would receive the click: ...

```
<a class="rtbWrap" href="#">
```

xPath:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_OverdueItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_GridToolbar"]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a
```

> **Keys.Enter:**
>         Nothing Happened

*

> *Click():**   WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (244, 149).
>   Other element would receive the click: ...

```
<span class="rtbIn">
```

xPath:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_OverdueItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_GridToolbar"]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span
```

> **Keys.Enter:**   WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
>
> **Click():**      WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (243, 147).
>   Other element would receive the click: ...

```
<img alt="" src="../images/icons/document-excel.png" class="rtbIcon">
```

xPath:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_OverdueItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_GridToolbar"]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span/img
```

> **Keys.Enter:**   WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
>
> **Click():**  WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element  is
>   not clickable at point (203, 150)

```
<span class="rtbText">Export to Excel</span>
```

xPath:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_OverdueItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_GridToolbar"]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span/span
```

> **Keys.Enter:**   WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
>
> **Click():**  WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (254, 150).

Comment: So you're not able to get the correct Xpath/Locator for this element?

Comment: Whay I did was to right click and copy the elements that I thought was right. The funny thing is that I don't even know how to know if the xPath is correct. So these xPaths are the result from copying the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace click event with action class, which will solve this Exception

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(firstContest).click().perform()
```

Comment: So what do I have to fill in within the FirstContest? I guess **rtbItem rtbBtn**. I'd try it.

Comment: @OliverBird  Your Clickable element -  Upcoming_Tasks

Comment: I did it. I even tried other element. But could you elaborate more why we have to use Action class?

Comment: @OliverBird Hope this doc will help you to understand. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html    
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

Comment: Thanks for the direction!