# Object is found but click does not happen

Tags: selenium, xpath, click

I am using `selenium` and `python` to do UI testing of my application.
The click works for some objects but not all.
This is the simplest form I have tried:

```
element = self.driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@id,'col1') and 
[starts-with(.,'" + text + "')])[1]"))              
element.click()
```

One issue that I have come across when I have tried to see if the `xpath` works is the following:
I manually clear the browsing data, log into my application, search for the object of interest.
Object is found.
I use the chrome developers tool and go to the Console and try the following xpath:

```
$x('//a[contains(@id,"col1") and starts-with(.,"Auto_Smk_SETask")][1]')
```

but no match is found.
I then go to Elements tab and select the object.
I go back to the Console and try the same xpath and this time it works.
Why is that the case? 
I have spent many hours on this with no luck!!!

Comment: Is the element you are looking for inside an iframe tag?

Comment: Please try with : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50960720/9405154

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check if the element is inside of an iframe in DevTools is to go to the console tab and see if the "top" element is available:

[image]

If there's an iframe element, it will show when you click the downward arrow.