# Cannot click buttons using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

According to 
[Cannot pull data from pantip.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004431/cannot-pull-data-from-pantip-com/54028100#54028100)
,I tried to pull data from pantip.com including all comments and reply of each comment.

[image]

I have a problem about getting reply text of each comment. I use selenium to click a button in order to get the text inside. However, it works only if I scroll the page to the location of the button.

Here is an error if I do not scroll.

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="reply see-more">...</a> is not clickable at point (518, 507). Other element would receive the click: <select class="dropdown-jump">...</select>
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Is there any way to get the data inside? Do I need to scroll to buttons?
Please suggest me.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
url='https://pantip.com/topic/38372443'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(url)

content=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')  

#Click all buttons
for div in soup.find_all("div", id = lambda value: value and value.startswith("reply-comment-")):
    xPath =  '''//*[@id="''' + str(div['id']) + '''"]/a''' 
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath).click()


# Get all comments   
text = list()    
for div in soup.find_all("div", id = lambda value: value and value.startswith("comment-")):
    if len(str(div.text).strip()) > 1:
        text.append(str(div.text).strip())
driver.quit()
```

Comment: As according to your exception details, You can use action class to click webelement, Here you may go https://stackoverflow.com/a/50960720/9405154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fixed navigation panel at the bottom of page, so when you're trying to click the button you actually clicks element from that panel and that's why Exception raised... You might need to

- scroll to required button
- scroll a bit down
- click the button to see reply

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  for reply in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "reply-comment-")]/a'):
      driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', reply)
      reply.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
      reply.click()
  ```

Comment: Thank you. It work, but why we have to "scroll a bit down".

Comment: @t.WandeeWandee , that's because when we do `scrollIntoView()` required link is still not clickable as it covered by fixed bottom panel. So one more key down press is required to make it completely visible/clickable

Answer (score 1):

To click on each *comment* button and extract the reply text of each comment you don't need *Beautiful Soup* and *Selenium* alone is enough. To achieve that you have to *scroll* the desired element into the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver= webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://pantip.com/topic/38372443")
  comment_buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.reply.see-more span.focus-txt")))
  for button in comment_buttons:
      driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)
      button.click()
      print("Comment button clicked")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='comment'][data-refcm^='comment'] div.display-post-story>a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Comment button clicked
  Comment button clicked
  Comment button clicked
  Comment button clicked
  https://www.instagram.com/clintbondad
  .
  .
  .
  ```

Comment: Thank you. It work. Could you  explain to me more how comment_buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until ... .. . works.

Comment: @t.WandeeWandee This line of code `comment_buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.reply.see-more span.focus-txt")))` collects the elements identified as **comment** button and stores in a list so we can invoke `click()` method on it through an iteration.

Answer (score 0):

selenium can execute script with `execute_script("xxxx")`, e.g:

```
script = """function getComments(){var comments=new Array();a = $('div.display-post-story');for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){comments.push(a[i].innerText)};return comments;}"""
comments = driver.execute_script(script)
# then u can deal with all comments.
```